# Easy algorithm with two loops

Tags: php

I need to write out like this:

```
6 5 4 3 2 
5 4 3 2 
4 3 2 
3 2 
2
```

i guess it's must be something like

```
for ($i = 6; $i > 1; $i--) {

    echo $i . " ";

}
```

Comment: Did you tried anything to find out if your guess was right?

Comment: my browser is crashed after my trying ))

Comment: Is it a homework assignment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got some PHP-Fu ?

```
$s = 7;$e = 2;

for($i=$s;$i>$e;){
    echo implode(' ',range(--$i, $e)) . '<br>';
}
```

or:

```
for ($e = 2, $i = 5; $i--;
    print(implode(' ', range($e + $i, $e)) . "\n")
);
```

Comment: +1 Wow...  (world of wonders)

Comment: +1 - Nice answer! Yours is nice of course, but still I find hakre's version cleaner! :)

Answer (score 5):

You need at least two loops:

```
$max = 6;
$min = 2;

for ($num = $max; $num >= $min; $num--) {
  for ($i=$num; $i >= $min; $i--) {
    echo $i . ' ';
  }
  echo "\r\n";
}
```

> 6 5 4 3 2 
> 5 4 3 2  
> 4 3 2 
>  3 2 
>  2

Codepad live example: http://codepad.org/FFvFPCwZ

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($x = 6; $x > 1; $x--) {
    for($y = $x; $y > 1; $y--) { 
        echo $y . " ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Uncompiled, untested and unverified, but it should work. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
for($j = 6; $j > 1; $j--){

    for ($i = $j; $i > 1; $i--) {

        echo $i . " ";

    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you might want to do some like this in the case of 1 digit, using strings instead numbers

```
$values = "65432"; // $values = join("", range(6, 2));
for($i = strlen($values); $i >= 1; $i--, $values = substr($values, 1)){
   echo $values . "<br>";
}
```

And the output

```
65432<br>5432<br>432<br>32<br>2<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close :)

Try this:

```
<?php

for ($i = 6; $i > 1; $i--) {

echo $i . " ";
    for ($z=$i-1; $z>=2; $z--) {
      echo $z . " ";
    }

    echo PHP_EOL;

}
```